# Javascript insert parameter inside string

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to ask if there is a way to insert variable inside another string which is part of another statement. For example:

```
function SomeFunction(field) {  

  var someVariable = document.getElementById('<%=' + field + '.ClientID %>');
}
```

But I've got an error:

```
Error   6   'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID'
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot mix server-side and client-side code like this.

Comment: Is that a JavaScript error? Aren't you using a server-side language like ASP?

Comment: @amemack: you have asked five questions and received seven answers so far over one month, but you haven't accepted any. How about rewarding those you found useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get a value from server-side tags, this won't work:

```
<%=' + field + '.ClientID %>
```

You need to do it some way so you only do this:

```
var someVariable = document.getElementById(field);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming field is say 'name' and you give id to name field as "name.4" where 4 is ClientID.

```
function SomeFunction(field) {  

      var someVariable = document.getElementById(field+".<%= ClientID.to_s %>");
    }
```